# Flutter: Have a row element be the size of its highest sibling

Tags: flutter

Here is pretty much what I want, but the grey container should match the height of the card. While the height of the card should fit the text content.

[image]

Here is the current code for that:

```
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
          border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.grey.shade400),
          color: Colors.grey.shade100),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Container(
                child: Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."))),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: const Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.edit_outlined),
                      Icon(Icons.delete_outlined)
                    ]),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
                width: 10,
                height: 50
                ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

But then I'd like to remove "height: 50" to autoresize the grey part...
I understand that I'm missing height constraints on that cart, but I don't understand how to do that, when I try I either get errors or the grey part doesn't show up...

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it (took me 2 days before I decided to post here, then 2 hours after I posted)...
Wrapping the Row inside an InstrasiftHeight widget did the trick